# Why do I get different results for the same integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-series

The variables $ a, b, s, c $ are constants, so:

$$ \int \left ( a \cos(s + cx) - b \sin(s + cx) \right ) dx = \frac{a\sin(s + cx) + b\cos(s + cx)}{c} +C $$

But if $c=0$ then:

$$ \int \left ( a  \cos(s) - b  \sin(s) \right ) dx = x( a\cos(s) + b\sin(s) ) +C $$

How is that possible? Why is the result different? At $c=0$ the first equation makes no sense, because the $c$ is in the denominator.

Comment: What you did for the first integral is *only valid* for $c \ne 0$; so what exactly are you asking now...?

Comment: I just can't understand, why is the first not valid at $ c = 0 $ and why is the second

Comment: @IterAtor It would make more sense to write: $$\int \left ( a \cos(s + cx) - b \sin(s + cx) \right ) dx = \frac{a\sin(s + cx) + b\cos(s + cx)}{c}+C$$ for $c\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the constant of integration be $C+(-a\sin s-b\cos s)/c$.  The first answer becomes $$\frac{a(\sin(s+cx)-\sin s)+b(\cos(s+cx)-\cos s)}c+C\\=\frac{2a\cos (s+\frac{cx}2)\sin\frac{cx}2-2b\sin(s+\frac{cx}2)\sin\frac{cx}2}c+C$$
The fundamental trigonometric limit $$\lim_{c\to0}\frac{\sin\frac{cx}2}c=\frac x2$$
lets you simplify my second line to your answer (with a sign error).

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you use $0$ as your constant inside the function, that whole function becomes a constant and is multiplied by $x$ for the integration.